# When did Batman first discover the existence of the paranormal/supernatural, and how did he react?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

In terms of publication history (first instance in published media, rather than first instance for the character's perspective in a particular story), when was the very first time that Batman discovers the existence of something that's considered to be either paranormal or supernatural, and how did he react to this?

For example, when was the first time in the real world that a comic book reader could pick up an issue and see Batman encountering an unambiguous ghost, or evidence of life after death.

And yes, I understand that there may be some blurring of the lines of what is paranormal and what isn't in DC comics. I'm discounting things like aliens, flesh and blood creatures from other dimensions, and meta-human powers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Batman's fifth appearance, in *[Detective Comics #31](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_31)* (1939), "Batman Versus The Vampire", Batman encounters [The Monk](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Niccolai_Tepes_(New_Earth)), a vampire or werewolf (he's described as both).

> The Monk was a vampire who wore a red, monk-like outfit, with a hood that bears a yellow skull and crossbones on it. He had an assistant named Dala, who lured Batman to their lair using Bruce Wayne's fiancé, Julie Madison, as bait.
>
> The Monk placed Julie in a hypnotic trance, but Batman managed to rescue her and afterwards, Batman killed the Monk and Dala by shooting them with silver bullets as they lay in their coffins.

In short, he seems to take the supernatural entirely in stride.

Comment: Did he comment on the existence of this creature in any way?

Comment: @AaarghZombies: Based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbF__NCzE98 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dcl65OXWNGQ, not really, with comments like "So, you are vampires" followed by immediately pursuing The Monk.

Comment: Was this before Batman decided he didn't shoot people?  Or do werewolf-vampires not count as people?

Comment: @DougWarren: Golden Age Batman didn't mess around. He routinely killed criminals, and there's a notorious image of him machine-gunning a set of mobsters with his Bat-Biplane.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots But only villains. For example, [ducks are beyond the pale](https://youtu.be/G4v1hAnfy1I) and yet Batman (admittedly inadvertently) kills baddies in the same movie.

Comment: Adam West was definitely much more peak Silver Age Batman. In fact, people have pointed out several comics issues that came out around that time that completely match the aesthetic of the show. As regards the shooting, and the somewhat flat response of Batman to vampires, they really were in early days with the character, and we're figuring out who he was.